# Unable to get a response from nginx pod when pinged through a busybox pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have two containers (Nginx and Busybox) running in different pods in the same namespace. Whenever I try to get a ping or wget from busybox pod to Nginx I am unable to do that and I not able to understand why is this happening as I should be able to communicate from pod to another.

Ngnix Pod Description

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

BusyBox Pod Description

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: busybox
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: busybox
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

Terminal Respose:

```
wget -O- 172.XX.XX.XXX:XX
Connecting to 172.XX.XX.XXX:XX (172.XX.XX.XXX:XX)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.XX.XX.XXX): Connection timed out
```

On loging I get this

```
2019/07/12 18:47:30 [error] 7#0: *1177 "/usr/local/nginx/html/nginx_status/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 404 error in nginx logs mentioned by you comes from the nginx host as the client says `localhost`. It has nothing to do with your connection timeout error.

How did you find the cluster IP of the pod? Usually, you can get the ip address with the command:

```sh
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

Check if you are using the correct ip in the wget command.

Comment: Yup I used the same command to find the IP of Ngnix pod and yes i check it again, the interesting part is it works on minikube but not on a cluster provided by a cloud provider.

Comment: What cloud provider are you using?

Comment: @YahirHernández IBM Cloud

Comment: Have your checked that there aren't any firewall rules applied to the inter-node communication? Also, if you schedule the pods within the same node, can they reach each other?

Comment: @YahirHernández having the pods on the same node worked. Thanx